# cmake find_library and CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH

Tags: c++, c, cmake

In the documentation for cmake's `find_library` function, we have

> The CMake variable CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH specifies one or more
>   directories to be prepended to all other search directories. This
>   effectively “re-roots” the entire search under given locations. Paths
>   which are descendants of the CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX are excluded from
>   this re-rooting, because that variable is always a path on the host
>   system. By default the CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is empty.
>
> The CMAKE_SYSROOT variable can also be used to specify exactly one
>   directory to use as a prefix. Setting CMAKE_SYSROOT also has other
>   effects. See the documentation for that variable for more.
>
> These variables are especially useful when cross-compiling to point to
>   the root directory of the target environment and CMake will search
>   there too. By default at first the directories listed in
>   CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH are searched, then the CMAKE_SYSROOT directory is
>   searched, and then the non-rooted directories will be searched. The
>   default behavior can be adjusted by setting
>   CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY. This behavior can be manually
>   overridden on a per-call basis. By using CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_BOTH the
>   search order will be as described above. If NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is
>   used then CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH will not be used. If
>   ONLY_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is used then only the re-rooted directories
>   and directories below CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX will be searched.

(see http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html)

I'm not sure how you read that, but to me, it seems implied that `find_library` will use `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` to look for libraries. I've written the following `cmakelists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )

project( "cmakefindlibtest" )

message( "CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}" )
list( APPEND CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "C:/DEV/lib/" )
message( "CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is now ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}" )
#find_library( punycode_library_test punycode PATHS "C:/DEV/lib" )
find_library( punycode_library_test punycode  )
message( "punycode_library_test is now ${punycode_library_test}" )

add_executable( cmakefindlibtest main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( cmakefindlibtest ${punycode_library_test} )
```

`main.cpp` is just hello world. In `C:\DEV\lib`, I've put a library named `punycode.lib` (this is on Windows). I've pointed `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` to the directory. And then when I call `find_library`, I get:

```
c:\DEV\cmakefindtest\_build>cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 11 2012
CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is
CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is now C:/DEV/lib/
punycode_library_test is now punycode_library_test-NOTFOUND
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
punycode_library_test
    linked by target "cmakefindlibtest" in directory C:/DEV/cmakefindtest

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/DEV/cmakefindtest/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Note that when I add the directory to the PATHS part of `find_library`'s invocation

```
find_library( punycode_library_test punycode PATHS "C:/DEV/lib" )
```

everything works:

```
c:\DEV\cmakefindtest\_build>cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 11 2012
CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is
CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is now C:/DEV/lib/
punycode_library_test is now C:/DEV/lib/punycode.lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/DEV/cmakefindtest/_build
```

So does `find_library` just not use `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`?

Update:

It looks like CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH mostly does what I want it to do here, and according to http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake-developers/2012-January/002850.html, it looks like that's what I should be using it for in this case anyways.

But, I'm still trying to figure out why `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` doesn't work with `find_library`. The documentation at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling says of `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`,

> this is a list of directories, each of the directories listed there
>   will be prepended to each of the search directories of every
>   FIND_XXX() command.

which doesn't seem to be true in this case, unless there's some sort of set-up or another variable that I've missed.

Comment: Would adding `C:/DEV/lib/` to `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` do the trick ? Look at http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487752/how-do-i-instruct-cmake-to-look-for-libraries-installed-by-macports `set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} C:/DEV/lib/)`

Comment: Just tried it, and this does work - if I set CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH, then find_library finds it.

Comment: Your update should actually be an answer, I'd upvote it, though it didn't help me completely.

Answer (score 3):

I have met the same problem when doing cross-compiling of openwrt, with an external toolchain specified.

Like the problem described, I have set the `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` to the toolchain's directory, but still, `rpcd` complains about missing crypt library.

Then I noticed this thread and figured may be it is because of implied lib search path of `./usr/lib` and `./lib`. As such, I changed the `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` to be the sysroot of the toolchain, which includes `./usr/lib` and `./lib` for the target platform, then the problem is gone.

Getting back to the original problem, I think maybe if you can try to set `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` to be `C:/DEV`, and place the library to be linked to under `C:/DEV/lib`.

That being said, if you are not doing a cross-compiling, this may not be the most sensible solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` will be prepended to a certain set of directories described in the [docs of find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html). It won't be prepended to the file names you specify for `find_library`.

You only need to use `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` for cross-compiling. For example, while `find_library(.. jpeg ...)` will find `/usr/lib/libjpeg.so`  you can hijack this search with `set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ~/my_toolchain)` to find `~/my_toolchain/usr/lib/libjpeg.so` instead.

Since you didn't mention you were cross-compiling what you probably need is [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html). Try `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "c:/DEV")` or `set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "c:/DEV/lib")` to make `find_library` search in `c:/DEV/lib`.