# Linking CGAL Library with XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, cgal

I have installed CGAL using macports. I run CMake on an example and its running fine.
So I tried to create a new project and pasted the code I needed from an example. So I have not link the CGAL libraries yet and unable to run the code. Im not sure how to link it in the build settings. Hope someone can guide me through.

Im trying to run the envelope2.cpp.

Comment: CGAL's doc explains how to use cmake for that.

Comment: Do you want to avoid using CMake?

Comment: I'd just love to have it build inside XCode, if there's any easy way to have XCode call their CMake script that'd be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mentioned MacPorts but here are instructions for Homebrew. They should be pretty similar but you might need to alter some of the paths from `/usr/local` to `/opt/local`.

### Install libraries

```
brew install cgal
```

### Add the includes

- Open the project settings.
- Select the project.
- Choose the `Build Settings` tab.
- Select the `All` filter.
- Search for `header search` and you'll find the right setting:
  [image: Found the setting]
- Double click on the path(s) next to `Header Search Paths`
- Click the `+` button on the detail popup:
  [image]
- Enter `/usr/local/include/`.
- Click outside the detail popup to close it.

### Add the libraries

- Open the project settings.
- Select the target.
- Choose the `General` tab.
- In the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section click the `+` button:
  [image]
- You'll get a selection dialog:
  [image: Add Framework and Library dialog]
- Click the `Add Other...` button and you'll get an open file dialog.
- Hit `Option + /` to go to a specific a directory:
  [image: Switch to /usr/local/lib]
- Enter `/usr/local/lib`, and click `Go`.
- Select the following files (hold `Command` while clicking to select more than one at at time):

  - `libboost_thread-mt.dylib`
  - `libCGAL.dylib`
  - `libCGAL_Core.dylib`
  - `libgmp.dylib`
  - `libmpfr.dylib`

Comment: Thanks for a detailed step-by-step answer. To further add on to this answer: 
I was still unable to compile my CGAL C++ program even after following above stepss. To make it work I made the following changes in the `Search Paths` tab:
- `Always Search User Paths` ---> `Yes`
- `User Header Search Paths `---> `/usr/local/include`

and it worked!

I don't understand why this extra steps were required, if anyone knows how to avoid these, please lemme know.

Comment: interesting,I'll add a note in next time I update these instructions for the new version.

Comment: For compiled code.
If I copy paste the executable to another pc and copy paste the .dylib files, would the executable could run? For now such workflow does not work.

Answer (score 0):

When `cgal` is installed on the system, the example `example/Envelope_2` (contains a `CMakeLists.txt` file) can be run like this:

```
cmake .
make
./convex_hull
```

Or for an out-of-source build:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
mv ../ch_points.dat .
./convex_hull
```

This is on OS X with `cgal` installed using brew, which installs into `/usr/local/...`. With MacPorts there may be a problem because it installs the third-party packages into `/opt`.

According to [How do I instruct CMake to look for libraries installed by MacPorts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487752/how-do-i-instruct-cmake-to-look-for-libraries-installed-by-macports) , adding the following to the `CMakeLists.txt` file (before `find_package`) may help:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/local/lib)
list(APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH /opt/local/include)
```

Comment: For the bounty I was really looking for some XCode specific instructions. I should have mentioned I'm working with an existing Cinder project so I tried manually adding the libraries and include path and that fixed most of the errors that popped up but got hung up on ld throwing a `duplicate symbol __Z3foov` error.

Comment: Ah so a quick `c++filt __Z3foov` shows my problems was trying to stick my `foo()` test function in a header that got included twice.