# cmake3: set path to mpi headers

Tags: c++, cmake, mpi

Based on [CMake: set path to MPI headers and binaries manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091579/cmake-set-path-to-mpi-headers-and-binaries-manually), I set up my cmake file as:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
SET(TARGET "test")
PROJECT(${TARGET})
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11" CACHE STRING "compile flags" FORCE)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
if (MPI_FOUND)
    include_directories(SYSTEM ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
else (MPI_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "couldn't find MPI")
endif (MPI_FOUND)
add_executable(${TARGET} somefiles)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
```

and it worked nicely. But when I do it with cmake3 as:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.13.4)
the rest is the same as above
```

I get this error:

```
CMake Error at /home/nourisaj/c++/WP1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_3d1ffTargets.cmake:16 (add_library):
  Target "MPI::MPI_C" links to item " -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib
  -Wl,--enable-new-dtags" which has leading or trailing whitespace.  This is
  now an error according to policy CMP0004.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/nourisaj/c++/WP1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:14 (include)


CMake Error at /home/nourisaj/c++/WP1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_3d1ffTargets.cmake:16 (add_library):
  Target "MPI::MPI_C" links to item " -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib
  -Wl,--enable-new-dtags" which has leading or trailing whitespace.  This is
  now an error according to policy CMP0004.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/nourisaj/c++/WP1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:14 (include)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake3/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1187 (try_compile):
  Failed to generate test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake3/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1228 (_MPI_try_staged_settings)
  /usr/share/cmake3/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1488 (_MPI_check_lang_works)
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into the [`CMP0004`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0004.html#cmp0004) policy error. In earlier versions of CMake, linked libraries automatically had any leading or trailing whitespace removed. This can lead to subtle, undesired errors in some cases, so CMake now enforces this policy, the `NEW` behavior requiring that linked libraries have *no* leading or trailing whitespace. It looks like one of your MPI targets is linking with this, which has a leading whitespace character:

```
" -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags"
```

Based on this CMake [issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/11881), this policy error appears to be fixed as of CMake 3.9. If you are running a CMake older than 3.9, you'll have to modify the `FindMPI.cmake` file yourself to either remove the leading whitespace, or you can tell CMake to use the old behavior for this policy (silently remove the leading whitespace):

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0004 OLD)
```

Here are the docs for [`cmake_policy`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_policy.html#setting-policies-explicitly). While setting this policy in the `FindMPI.cmake` file may work, it is not recommended. The CMake policy was put in place to avoid the `OLD` behavior, so it is recommended you remove the whitespace manually from the file.

**NOTE:** As is always the case when testing with different versions of CMake, make sure you are deleting the CMake cache and building from scratch when switching versions.

Comment: I added `cmake_policy(SET CMP0004 OLD)` to my cmake file didnt help. still getting the same error.

Comment: where to find this `you can either edit the MPI CMake file(s) `? in my error it says ` /home/nourisaj/c++/WP1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:` but the file doesnt exist

Comment: I am working on a cluster and no idea where it's cmake files are located.  Do you have any idea how to find it out?

Comment: @JalilNourisa The CMake installation comes with a `FindMPI.cmake` file, within which you can set the policy, or modify the linker flags to remove the whitespace. In the CMake installation, it is located here: `share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindMPI.cmake`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197285/discussion-between-squareskittles-and-jalil-nourisa).

Comment: I just removed built file and created make file from scratch and it turned out working fine! you can add this to the top of your answer to make it completed so I will go ahead and confirm your answer

Comment: @JalilNourisa I added a note for that to my answer, although refreshing your CMake cache applies to all situations when testing with different CMake versions. Glad it's working!