# How to set the search priority for library in cmake

Tags: linux, cmake

I was trying to install opencv in one machine. And I met with an issue: for the library libavcodec-dev there are two copies in the machine,
 `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib`. The version in `/usr/lib` is compatible with opencv. But CMake found `/usr/local/lib` first. Could anyone help me? How to configure the cmake to find correct version? Thanks.

Comment: This question has extensive information on how to affect the linking of libs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487752/how-do-i-instruct-cmake-to-look-for-libraries-installed-by-macports

Answer (score 3):

To specify a specific lib "Foo" found exactly in `/usr/lib` you should use;

```
find_library(Foo foo PATHS /usr/lib NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_library.html);

> If NO_DEFAULT_PATH is specified, then no additional paths are added to
>   the search.

Documentation also goes on to say that the default search for libs are dictated and controlled by the `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable.

Comment: I don't think this will work; it only appends the given `PATHS` to the *end* of the paths to search.

Comment: Updated the answer -- have a look

Answer (score 1):

```
find_library(AVCODEC avcodec-dev PATHS /usr/lib NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

Comment: Is there any general way to change the search path order? Since there are many libraries in such case. Thanks.

Comment: @Alfred: I'm not really sure what you're asking now.